# Angular 2 orderByPipe showing nothing on start

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am thinking that the reason it is showing nothing at the start is because it is not async so just returns an empty array. Without the pipe it works fine but on startup the posts are not shown. After I submit a post it shows all the posts and they are sorted.

The issue is when I refresh the page the posts do not show. If I submit a new post or go to a different route and come back then they show.

Here is the html part:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of postContainers | orderByPipe">
```

I have tried using:   postContainers | orderByPipe | async
But the async part seems to do nothing.

When just the following is used it works fine and shows the posts on startup, but is not sorted.

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of postContainers">
```

My pipe is:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'orderByPipe'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform{

     transform(array: Array<string>, args: string): Array<string> {

     if(!array || array === undefined || array.length === 0) return null;

    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (this.convertDate(a.date) < this.convertDate(b.date)) {
        return -1;
      } else if (this.convertDate(a.date) > this.convertDate(b.date)) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }

  convertDate(timestamp: any) {
    return new Date(timestamp*1000);
  }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why dont you put the async pipe BEFORE the orderByPipe instead of after ?

Comment: I had tried that and got: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid argument '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `*ngIf`-directive on your dom-element. The Dom element will therefore wait until the data is received before rendering it, and the orderByPipe should work:

```
<li *ngIf="postContainers" *ngFor="let item of postContainers | orderByPipe">
```

Comment: It gave an error having both ngIf and ngFor on one element to tried the ngIf on a surrounding span, and also tried it on the <ul> but both did nothing.